# String форматированный вывод

Tags: c#

Например `int x = 15300;`
Хочу чтобы `x` выводилось так: `15,300`.
Пользуюсь таким форматированием `x.ToString("0','000"));`
Выводит нормально, но когда `x < 1000` то выводит 0,450, а надо чтоб выводило просто 450. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно так?

```
    int x = 15000;
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo( "en-US" ))); // 15,000

    x = 450;
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo( "en-US" ))); // 450
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), "{0:N0}", x);
```

Переключает форматирование на американский лад, и форматирует число в соответствии с этим форматом. Взято [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
int x = 15000;
string result = String.Format("{0:0,#}", x).Replace(((char)160).ToString(), ",");
```

Comment: Написал так x.ToString("{0:0,#}").Replace(((char)160).ToString(), ",")); Вывелось так: 15000

Comment: Напишите так, как дал в примере. String.Format и т.д., где x - ваше число.

Comment: У меня метод возвращает int значение, поэтому хочется сразу к методу применить ToString и в параметре написать то что мне нужно, уверен что так можно сделать но не знаю как

Comment: DreamChild ответил.